# RelativeLayout position and merge

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to 'float' a `RelativeLayout` to the bottom of a `Window`, and have the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <com.my.activity.CanvasView
    android:id="@+id/canvas"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:focusable="true" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_notification"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="bottom|center_vertical">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_notification_icon"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/content_desc_save_icon"
            android:gravity="center|center_vertical" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</merge>
```

Unfortunately, the `toolbar_notification` `RelativeLayout` is not being bottom-aligned. Replacing the `merge` tag with a `FrameLayout` tag results in the desired effect, but in the name of efficiency I'd like to remove that if possible.

Anyone seen this issue, or have any suggestions? Is the fact that the `merge` element is not a 'parent' in the true sense resulting in the `toolbar_notification` element being unable to place itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`android:gravity="bottom|center_vertical"` is referred to children of `RelativeLayout` and not to `RelativeLayout` itself.

If you want to align `RelativeLayout` to the bottom of the parent (that is a `FrameLayout`) you have to use `layout_gravity` instead.

```
...
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_notification"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_vertical">
 ...
```